# COUNT function with the example code below

Tags: sql, postgresql

Another question i got. Thanks for the time in advance.
Which table is it counting from?
the **result of the query table**,
or the **original table** *?* - and if so ,which original table *?*

```
SELECT
  DATE_PART('year', registration_date) AS registration_year,
  channel_name,
  COUNT(*) AS registration_count
FROM customers cu
JOIN channels ch
  ON cu.channel_id = ch.id
GROUP BY DATE_PART('year', registration_date), channel_name
ORDER BY DATE_PART('year', registration_date);
```

HAVE A GREAT DAY.

Answer (score 0):

Your `COUNT(*)` expression is counting on the result of the query, namely the join of the `customers` table and the `channels` table. That result is then grouped and PostgreSQL returns the count of the joined and grouped table.

In general, the `SELECT` expression will operate on the results of the [table expression](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-table-expressions.html). In your example you compute as a [join table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-JOIN). To quote the documentation,

> The result of the FROM list is an intermediate virtual table that can then be subject to transformations by the WHERE, GROUP BY, and HAVING clauses and is finally the result of the overall table expression.

Comment: So that table is an imaginary one, just blended on the key defined in the JOIN clause. Right? i mean it isnt a visible table. Am i correct? (kind of inbetween table)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I added some more details to my answer that hopefully clarify what's going on.